# MySQL GROUP BY next row in table for foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table which contains "work" for a given "project" and I would like to get the next row out of the table for each project.

```
TABLE project { id, name }
TABLE work {id, project_id, value, done}
```

What is the correct, performant query for getting new work one at a time until it's all done? The following query doesn't work and replacing the select columns with `min(columnhere)` results in mis-matched results from multiple rows.

```
SELECT w.id, p.name, w.value FROM work w
LEFT JOIN project p ON p.id = w.project_id
GROUP BY project_id
```

Results from the above query should look like this:

```
34,  "Project 1", "Work 43", "..."
21,  "Project 2", "Work 10", "..."
321, "Project 3", "Work 86", "..."
```

Comment: Is it the same question?

Comment: Please post your desired result table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly and you need one (not yet done) work at a time for each project then are looking for something like this

```sql
SELECT n.id, n.project_id, p.name project, w.value work
  FROM
(
  SELECT project_id, MIN(id) id
    FROM work
   WHERE done = 0
   GROUP BY project_id
) n JOIN work w
    ON n.id = w.id JOIN project p
    ON n.project_id = p.id
```

Explanation:

1. grab the very first id of the work that is not done yet per project. The assumption here is that the work is ordered by id.
2. join back to `work` to get all other work values based on id
3. join to `projects` to get project names
   Sample output:

```
+------+------------+-----------+---------+
| id   | project_id | project   | work    |
+------+------------+-----------+---------+
|   43 |         34 | Project 1 | Work 43 |
|   10 |         21 | Project 2 | Work 10 |
|   86 |        321 | Project 3 | Work 86 |
+------+------------+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: Nice. The query works but is slow unless you add an an index on both columns in the subquery: `index(done,project_id)`. Even then MySQL still has to sort through almost all rows in the table.

Comment: Sure. That goes without saying that you need appropriate indexes in place.

Comment: Then if anyone can figure out the appropriate indexes then please let us know.